# Need help counting occurences with respect to multiple columns with multiple conditions (including a partial string), then aggregating those results

Tags: r, aggregate, subset, grepl

Im having trouble finding a parsimonious way to do the following:

I need to count how many times the following is true for an **entire** row:
`“t2”`, `x2=4`, `x3=0`

In the following dataframe this is true for rows 8, 10 and 19. So the answer would be
**(t2, x2=4, x3=0) = 3** because that iteration happens twice.

```
     x1 x2 x3
1  t2xy  1  0
2  m1xy  3  0
3  m2xy  3  0
4  t1xy  4  1
5  m1yx  3  1
6  m2xy  3  1
7  m2yx  3  0
8  t2yx  4  0
9  t1xy  4  0
10 t2yx  4  0
11 m2yx  1  0
12 m1xy  3  0
13 m2yx  3  0
14 m2xy  1  0
15 t2yx  4  1
16 t2xy  1  1
17 m1xy  2  1
18 t1xy  2  1
19 t2xy  4  0
20 t1yx  2  1
```

I need to do this for each partial string match: t1, t2, m1, m2
And stored in either their own variables or aggregated somehow. Here is an example of all of the permutations for **t1**:

```
(t1, x2=1, x3=0) = 12
(t1, x2=1, x3=1) = 15
(t1, x2=2, x3=0) = 7
(t1, x2=2, x3=1) = 6
(t1, x2=3, x3=0) = 11
(t1, x2=3, x3=1) = 9
(t1, x2=4, x3=0) = 9
(t1, x2=4, x3=1) = 13
```

(*These outputs are just examples and not reflective of the above dataframe*)

This would also be done for t2, m1,and m2 permutations.

Here is the code I used to create some fake data:

```
x1<- sample(c("t1xy", "t2xy", "m1xy", "m2xy","t1yx", "t2yx", "m1yx", "m2yx"), 20, replace = T)
x2<- sample(1:4, 20, replace = T)
x3<- sample(0:1, 20, replace = T)

df_x <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3)
df_x
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are those values in counts 12, 15, etc based on the example or is it dummy?

Comment: Based on the logic, it can be `library(dplyr);df_x %>% count(x1 = substr(x1, 1, 2), x2, x3)`, but the count you showed is not matching

Comment: Those are just dummy numbers. Sorry, i should have specified.

Comment: Then, can you test the code in the comment above.  It should work

Comment: But it is also true for row 10 ?

Comment: Yes! Thank you for catching that! Fixed.

Comment: @akrun Sorry akrun, but this appears to select the first few characters in the string, it doesnt use those characters as parameters to classify the row in any meaningful way, unless there is something i am missing. It would need another argument to do that, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `add_count` with the conditions:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  add_count(t2 = str_detect(x1, "t2") & x2==4 & x3==0)
```

```
     x1 x2 x3    t2  n
1  t2xy  1  0 FALSE 17
2  m1xy  3  0 FALSE 17
3  m2xy  3  0 FALSE 17
4  t1xy  4  1 FALSE 17
5  m1yx  3  1 FALSE 17
6  m2xy  3  1 FALSE 17
7  m2yx  3  0 FALSE 17
8  t2yx  4  0  TRUE  3
9  t1xy  4  0 FALSE 17
10 t2yx  4  0  TRUE  3
11 m2yx  1  0 FALSE 17
12 m1xy  3  0 FALSE 17
13 m2yx  3  0 FALSE 17
14 m2xy  1  0 FALSE 17
15 t2yx  4  1 FALSE 17
16 t2xy  1  1 FALSE 17
17 m1xy  2  1 FALSE 17
18 t1xy  2  1 FALSE 17
19 t2xy  4  0  TRUE  3
20 t1yx  2  1 FALSE 17
```

Comment: This is great. Much better than the 100s of lines of noob code i was trying. When all is said and done, i can probably do it in about 5 lines using this format.